# Add back/forward buttons for viewing different Treeview Items without breaking limits

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

I want to navigate between some `TreeViewItem` using back/forward buttons. I can actually do that but my problem is that i can't make it stop going outside the limits. There's an example of my code for a forward button:

```
private void MainUser_button_next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach (TreeViewItem i in TreeviewUsers.Items)
        {
            if (i.Equals(MainTreeView.SelectedItem))
            {
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }
        (TreeviewUsers.Items[index + 1] as TreeViewItem).IsSelected = true;

    }
```

With the code I'm showing above it is possible to navigate forward but it breaks after it gets more that it's limits. I know I need to bind a limit but I don't know where to do that!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think `i.Equals(MainTreeView.SelectedItem)` is ever `true`, because TreeViewItem can't be in 2 TreeViews at the same time

Comment: I agree that may not be needed but taking it off won't solve my problem :/ Thanks tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible answer, depending on the behavior you want

```
(TreeviewUsers.Item[(index+1)%TreeviewUser.Item.Count]  as TreeViewitem).IsSelected = true;
```

or this line (try for the *back* case)

```
(TreeviewUsers.Item[mod((index+1),TreeviewUser.Item.Count)]  as TreeViewitem).IsSelected = true;
```

and define somewhere

```
int mod(int x, int m) {
    int r = x%m;
    return r<0 ? r+m : r;
}
```

By the way, can't you change this code

```
int index = 0;
foreach (TreeViewItem i in TreeviewUsers.Items)
{
    if (i.Equals(MainTreeView.SelectedItem))
    {
        break;
    }
    index++;
}
```

with this here

```
int index = TreeviewUsers.Items.Select((v, i) => new {v, i}).Where(x => x.v.Equals(MainTreeView.SelectedItem)).Select(x => x.i);
```

Comment: That first line of code solved my problem and now it works like i want to! Thanks mate!

Comment: Update: It solved for the "forward" button but not for the "back" one. When it reaches zero it crashes :(